Настройка DNS для маршрутизации почты на соответствующие поддомены
Я пытаюсь настроить DNS для обработки почты на множестве поддоменов, где каждый поддомен имеет свой собственный почтовый сервер. Моя цель - чтобы почта для адреса user@%subdomain%.example.com направлялась на сервер, размещенный под доменом %subdomain%.example.com.
Пример желаемой конфигурации:

Почта для user@abcde.example.com должна обрабатываться сервером abcde.example.com
Почта для user@xyz.example.com должна обрабатываться сервером xyz.example.com

И так далее для всех возможных поддоменов. Поддоменов много, поэтому вручную добавлять для каждого из них MX-запись не вариант.
Что может сработать
_smtp._tcp.*.example.com. IN SRV 0 0 25 %.example.com.

Такая конфигурация выглядит логично, но не знаю насколько она поддерживается почтовыми серверами. Не знаю возможно ли аналогичное для IMAP и POP3
Вопросы

Какие DNS-записи нужно создать, чтобы реализовать такую схему маршрутизации?

Возможно ли настроить wildcard MX-запись, которая будет автоматически направлять почту на соответствующий поддомен?

Если wildcard MX-запись невозможна, как можно автоматизировать процесс создания MX-записей для новых поддоменов (желательно так, чтобы это не занимало много времени, может быть используя dynamic DNS)?


Что не подходит

wildcard направление всех поддоменов на единый домен, типа *.example.com. IN MX 10 central-mail.example.com.. Такая конфигурация приемлема только при условии, что дальше письмо можно будет смаршрутизировать на нужный сервер без необходимости расшифровывать содержимое пакета (типа SNI в TLS/SSL)

Буду признателен за подробное объяснение необходимых DNS-записей и любые дополнительные пожелания
